# Is there a way to externally check the status of each task in a DAG?

Tags: airflow

I was looking through the different API endpoints that Airflow offers, but I could not find one that would suite my needs.  Essentially I want to monitor the state of each task within the DAG, without having to specify each task I am trying to monitor.  Ideally, I would be able to ping the DAG and the response would tell me the state of the task/tasks and what task/tasks are running/retrying...etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use the airflow rest api which comes along with it - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html

Comment: Is there a specific endpoint that you would recommend looking at ?

Comment: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_dag_runs - Provides the state of the DAG run.